# Tabindex is not applying in DOM at all

Tags: javascript, html, web, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I am trying to apply focus to a modal when it is active by setting tabindex="" in the code but unfortunately browsers (checked in Chrome and FF) doesn't show the attribute.

To solve this, I tried giving tabindex to a blank div tag but it didn't work there either.

This is the code in my editor.

```
<div className="modalBox" id="returnBookModalPanel" tabindex="0" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">
<div tabindex="0"></div>
```

---

Code rendered by browsers

```
<div class="modalBox" id="returnBookModalPanel" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">
<div></div>
```

I am following the accessibility standard too https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#dialog_roles_states_props

Comment: Hi, given that you are using React, give `tabIndex` a try?
More context: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: That didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I added some Dummy-text to your html, but if you run the snippet you can see that you can tab to the divs. So the attribute is not ignored by browsers. 
Maybe some JS or something is removing the attribute?

```html
<div className="modalBox" id="returnBookModalPanel" tabindex="0" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">
Content 1
<div tabindex="0">Content 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The thing is, there isn't any JS removing that particular attribute. It is a react app and DOM elements have been hard-coded.